# foreach loop duplicates values php sql

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Why this double foreach loop duplicates values

```
 foreach($_POST['studentpoints'] as $value) {
        foreach($_POST['studentids'] as $valor) {
            $stmt->bindParam(':studentid', $studentids);
            $stmt->bindParam(':studentpoints', $points);
            $studentids = $valor; 
            $points = $value;
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

This code don't duplicate the values, but only read the first id for students

```
foreach($_POST['studentpoints'] as $value) { 
        foreach($_POST['studentids'] as $valor) {
           $studentids = $valor;
        }

   $stmt->bindParam(':studentid', $studentids);
            $stmt->bindParam(':studentpoints', $points);
            $studentids = $valor; 
            $points = $value;
            $stmt->execute();

}
```

Table with data from database

```
<?php foreach($rowstudents as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="hidden" name="studentids[]" value="<?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($row['studentid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ';?>" />
    <?php echo '' . htmlentities($row['studentid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>  
    <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($row['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
    <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($row['lname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th> 
    <th><input type="text" name="studentpoints[]" value="<?php echo '' . htmlentities($row['studentpoints'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '' ?>"></th>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You are calling double foreaches that's why

Comment: It is posible to convert this two loop into one?

Comment: Probably, I'd create some sort of `student` object that comprises the entire row.  Then you just iterate over the students and pull out the relevant information.  Barring that, you'd need a `for` loop to get indexes - which would require a bit more error-checking.  Why can't you just do `$stmt->bindParam(':studentid', $valor);` (although this wouldn't solve your duplication problem)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yes i try that but I still getting the duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['studentpoints']); $i++) {
           $studentids = $_POST['studentid'][$i]; 
           $points = $_POST['studentpoints'][$i];

           $stmt->bindParam(':studentid', $studentids);
           $stmt->bindParam(':studentpoints', $points);
           $stmt->execute();

   }
```

Comment: Thank, I im trying this but it gives a warning Warning: Illegal string offset 'studentid' in and a error Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in

Comment: One again thank you, but now a different error Error 1 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'studentid' cannot be null

Comment: I modify my question if want to take a look to what Im trying

Comment: Edited my approach, try the new one.

Comment: Hmm...This is valid, but there's something misleading about a variable holding a _singular id_ as a plural: `studentids`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a for each loop twice. Apart from that it doesn't seem there is any problem

Comment: Yeah I see that :/ what Im trying to do is to convine those two loops into one